# Azure Functions Storage Account Different Than Queues

Tags: azure-functions

I know that Microsoft recommends Azure Functions to use their own storage account. My `Azure Function App` has multiple functions in it which need to get messages from `Azure Storage Queues` which are on a different storage account.

Can an `Azure Function` read messages from a `Storage Queue` that is under a different storage account -- within the same subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the "Connection" property on the QueueTriggerAttribute to specify the specific connection string you wish to use.  See the "QueueTriggerAttribute" section on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations.

Example from docs:

```
[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] string myQueueItem, 
    ILogger log)
{
    ....
}
```

Note, the value of the Connection property is the name of an app setting that contains the connection string, NOT the connection string itself.

Comment: Super useful! Thank you!